# Left eigenvectors not giving correct (markov) stationary probability in scipy

Tags: python, scipy, markov-chains

Given the following Markov Matrix:

```
import numpy, scipy.linalg
A = numpy.array([[0.9, 0.1],[0.15, 0.85]])
```

The stationary probability exists and is equal to `[.6, .4]`. This is easy to verify by taking a large power of the matrix:

```
B = A.copy()
for _ in xrange(10): B = numpy.dot(B,B)
```

Here `B[0] = [0.6, 0.4]`. So far, so good. According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix):

> A stationary probability vector is defined as a vector that does not change under application of the transition matrix; that is, it is defined as a left eigenvector of the probability matrix, associated with eigenvalue 1:

So I should be able to calculate the **left** eigenvector of `A` with eigenvalue of 1, and this should also give me the stationary probability. [Scipy's implementation of `eig`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html#scipy.linalg.eig) has a left keyword:

```
scipy.linalg.eig(A,left=True,right=False)
```

Gives:

```
(array([ 1.00+0.j,  0.75+0.j]), array([[ 0.83205029, -0.70710678],
   [ 0.5547002 ,  0.70710678]]))
```

Which says that the dominant left eigenvector is: `[0.83205029, 0.5547002]`. Am I reading this incorrectly? How do I get the `[0.6, 0.4]` using the eigenvalue decomposition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `[0.83205029, 0.5547002]` is just `[0.6, 0.4]` multiplied by ~1.39.

Although from "physical" point of view you need eigenvector with sum of its components equal 1, [scaling eigenvector by some factor does not change it's "eigenness"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvector):

If [image: \vec{v} A = \lambda \vec{v}], then obviously [image: (\alpha \vec{v}) A = \lambda (\alpha \vec{v})]

So, to get `[0.6, 0.4]` you should do:

```
>>> v = scipy.linalg.eig(A,left=True,right=False)[1][:,0]
>>> v
array([ 0.83205029,  0.5547002 ])
>>> v / sum(v)
array([ 0.6,  0.4])
```

Comment: Oh, of course. R(ing)TFM shows that `eig` returns the vectors normalized. In my head, I was expecting a normalized probability distribution (L1 norm) while scipy gave the more obvious sqrt of the sum of squares (L2 norm). In hindsight, I should have noticed that the ratio of the two components were the same in both cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the `eig` function returns *unit vector* as far as eigenvectors are concerned.

So, if we take
`v = [0.6, 0.4]`, its *length* is:
`l = np.sqrt(np.square(a).sum())` or `l = np.linalg.norm(v)`, so the normalized vector (as returned from `scipy.linalg.eig`) is:

```
>>> v = np.array([.6, .4])
>>> l = np.sqrt(np.square(a).sum())
>>> v / l
array([0.83205029, 0.5547002 ])
```

So, if you need the vector to be a *stochastic vector* or *probability vector* as in Markov chain, simply scale it so it sums to 1.0